# SQL Server 2012 - Convert CYYMMDD date to YYYYMMDD

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I have a table with just over 200,000 entries where the date is stored as CYYMMDD where C is the century (currently stored as integers). For example, December 5, 1992 would show up as `1921205` and April 25, 2016 would show up as `2160425`. I need to display these results in a new table in a YYYMMDD format. So for the two examples earlier it would be `19921205` and `20160425`. I have tried using

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),[DATE], 112)
```

This doesn't give an error but it also doesn't do the conversion so all my dates still look the same. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not just store the values as an actual `DATE` datatype, rather than converting it to a `VARCHAR`?

Comment: When I try to convert to date by using `CONVERT(DATE, [DATE], 112)` I get the following error: Explicit conversion from data type int to date is not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to split your numeric value as follows:

`DATEFROMPARTS( 1800 + FLOOR([DATE]/10000) , FLOOR([DATE]/100)%100, [DATE]%100 )`

Comment: `[Date]` is an `INT` datatype, not a `VARCHAR`.

Comment: 1800 should be 1900.